# struct system.Int32 does not have type parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I kept receiving the error message:

> struct system.Int32 does not have type parameters

in my interface method below. Does anyone know what am doing wrong?

```
public class StatementRptParamId {
  public Int32 ReportParameterId { get; set; }
}


public interface IStatementRptParamId {
  Int32<StatementRptParamId> GetStatementRptParameter(string connectionString, string customerNumber);
}
```

Error happens on this line: `Int32<StatementRptParamId>...`

Comment: What do you want to return in that method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `Int32` as a generic, which is incorrect. It looks like you think you're specifying the return type of your method call, which you also don't need to do. You've already given a type to the name. Just change your definition to:

```
StatementRptParamId GetStatementRptParameter(string connectionString, 
    string customerNumber);
```

You can then use the field on the class to get your value:

```
var val = GetStatementRptParameter(someConnectionString, someCustomerNumber);
var id = val.ReportParameterId;
```